# Reusable headers from xib

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I create table view with reusable headers. Something strange going on with headers when I load it from xib
[image]

```
- (UIView*)dequeueReusableHeaderView
{
    NSInteger indexAvailableView = [reusableHeaders indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    { return  [obj superview] == nil; }];

    return (indexAvailableView != NSNotFound)? reusableHeaders[indexAvailableView] : nil;
}

- (void)enqueueReusableView:(UIView*)headerView
{
    [reusableHeaders addObject:headerView];
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    BGDiaryHeader *header = (BGDiaryHeader*)[self dequeueReusableHeaderView];
    if (!header) {
        UINib *headerNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BGDiaryHeader_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *aNib = [headerNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        BGDiaryHeader *header = [aNib objectAtIndex:0];

    //if simple [[_ alloc]init] all works fine
    //    header = [[BGDiaryHeader alloc] init];
        [self enqueueReusableView:header];
    }
    //set display data
    return header;
}
```

If I create header view in code, all works fine

Comment: Did you step through the code and see if it returns a non-nil header?

Comment: Thanks!!!! Stupid I am shaddowed header varible in if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*header* shaddowed in *if* block

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    BGDiaryHeader *header = (BGDiaryHeader*)[self dequeueReusableHeaderView];
    if (!header) {
        UINib *headerNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BGDiaryHeader_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *aNib = [headerNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        header = [aNib objectAtIndex:0];

        [self enqueueReusableView:header];
    }
    //set display data
    return header;
}
```